# hyperlink text to URL not working on iPad

Tags: objective-c

i'm trying to link users on my app to a certain website, but i can't seem to get it working, been looking for a few hours but still no solution.

```
-(IBAction)hypertext:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"This should load hypertext");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.youtube.com"]];
}
```

This is my code, it's linked to a button,i know this is running because of the nslog.  But its not going to the url, or to safari to load it.  What am i doing wrong?  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Do you want it to launch safari and open that URL, or do you want it to open the URL within your own app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should add protocol: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"**http://**www.youtube.com"]`

Comment: whats with the *?  Don't get it.

Comment: Yes, its only for emphasizing. I think it will be bold

Comment: Ahh, right okay got it working now :).  cheers, silly mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

NSLog(@"This should load hypertext");

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]]`;

Its working fine.. I checked.